How to enable product wise product wise shipping in WordPress WooCommerce?
What are the most effective methods to implement product-specific shipping options in WordPress WooCommerce, allowing for both free and paid shipping on a per-product basis? Are there any recommended plugins or custom coding solutions that can seamlessly integrate this functionality while maintaining a user-friendly experience for both site administrators and customers?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
